# HTML 5 Validation not working

Tags: html, validation, date

I used MAX attribute to disable the future dates in  HTML 5. The Future Dates are disabled. But Still I'm unable select date less that that. Error message is saying that I should select date less that that.

Here is my Code.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <label class="control-label">Date</label>
    <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="Accident_Date" required  />
</div>

<script>
  var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
  document.getElementsByName("Accident_Date")[0].setAttribute('max', today);
</script>
```

The following screen shot shows the output. Although I've selected a date less than today, Its showing error message. I'm using parsley for validations.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't add the image

Comment: Does the browser console show any errors?
Also can you switch to "document.getElementById" and assign an id to the input element. That is faster, does not return arrays (id has to be unique), and is easier to use.

Comment: Even if i Hard-code the max value with today's date, I still get the error.
The date I selected is 2015-06-26
The error I'm getting is 
This value should be lower than or equal to 2015-06-27.

Comment: So we can be pretty certain the date is not passed to the code checking the date: Add a debug line in the code checking the date to see which value is passed and go from there.

Comment: The Date is getting passed. In the Date picker future dates are disabled. The problem is when I select a valid date Validation shows select a date less than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for trying. The error was with the library conflicting with html5 Library. The update of that library solved the error.

Thanks